# How to connect proxySQL cluster

Tags: proxysql

We are planning to setup a three node proxysql cluster with five mysql backend nodes. But how the application will connect to proxysql servers?

I have completed the setup and stuck how to use the cluster, Do we need to use any VIP or extra setup is required? Can some one please clarify me?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I accomplished.

A VIP has been assigned to proxysql servers and provided that VIP to users to connect the DB cluster.

Comment: If you want this to be considered a real question and answer, post some code so others can benefit from this post.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).